# I am having troubles with making a button do something

Tags: android

I am new to android studio so please help me! 
I am a 11 year old and I am intrested in app programming.
Any help is appreciated
It keeps on saying that the it cannot resolve symbol 'button'
This is my Java code:

```
package com.example.lenovouser.firstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.button;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button btn = (button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoMagic);

    }

}
```

Comment: button Class Starts with Capital Letter Button so insted of button btn = (button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoMagic); 
use
Button  btn = (button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoMagic);

Comment: Please post your activity_main layout so we can check everything is good there :)

Comment: Button btn = (button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoMagic);

Comment: Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoMagic);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your forgot to write the Uppercase letter Button since it is an Object.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoMagic);
```

Comment: Thank You so much!

Answer (score -1):

You capitalization is incorrect on this line:

`import android.widget.Button;`